# Can't find any new apps on the windows 8 store

Tags: windows-8

I am using Windows 8 Release preview and I can´t find any new apps on the windows store. All I see and find when I search are the same apps from months ago. I don´t see anything new like Skype, Netflix, Hulu Plus and LastPass. I have searched and can´t find an answer to this problem. My only guess is because I am using Windows 8 Release preview, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Release Preview will expire in January 2013, so you should upgrade to the RTM. There are some API changes, so I think this is why you don't get any new apps offered, because they don't work.